# Double comparing fails in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, compare, double

This line of code:

```
Response.Write("isEqual check:" + (val1 = val2).ToString + "[" + val1.ToString + ":" + val2.ToString + "]")
```

exactly outputs this:

> isEqual check:False[5998,88:5998,88]

As you can see, they're exactly same (but appearently not?)

Note: val1 is the result of a mathematical calculation and val2 is coming from a database field like this:

```
Dim val2 as Double = CDbl(datarow("amount"))
```

Comment: Are you certain val1 is a double?

Comment: Yes, since in VB.NET all mathematical calculations return as Double type. x1 * x2 can only be Double. Besides, I'm defining it as Double at first place.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I noticed that it was a .NET thing. We just can't compare Double types directly like that. I needed to write a dumb function to check if they're actually same by a tolerance level. Here what I did:

```
Function isEqual(v1 as Double, v2 as Double, Optional tolerance as Double = 0.0001) as Boolean
Return Math.Abs(v1 - v2) < tolerance
End Function
```